# Parallel forking using TSILO module in kamailio

Tags: voip, kamailio

I tried to use TSILO Kamailio module to implement push notification VoIP calls with IOS.
My problem is that i need to do a parallel forking of the call and send INVITES to every registered device for the same user. When i use parallel forking (without TSILO), and one of the devices answer the call, parallel forking automatically cancel the request that went to the other devices.
That is not the case when i use TSILO. Is TSILO ready to cancel branches when doing parallel forking?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Outgoing branches management is done by **tm** module. The **tsilo** module only keeps track of active transactions per user and can add new outgoing branches as the user is registering. When a branch is answered with 200ok, the transaction is completed, the rest of active branches are canceled (if they got some 1xx response) and no new branches should be created.

In other words, yes, Kamailio should cancel all other active branches when one is answered with 200ok, no matter how the branches are created, with or without tsilo.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply miconda.
We are using kamailio 4.4.5 stable for production. What happens in our configuration when use TSILO is that Kamailio is creating a new transaction with every new branch.
When we do parallel forking without TSILO all branches belong to the same transaction. So, in our case the new transactions branches are not cancelled, they continue ringing